# Golang このサイトにアクセスできません

Tags: go

golangのmain.goを実行したらこのサイトにアクセスできませんって出ます
これは何らかの問題が発生したのですか？ (何にもいじっていません)

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "html/template"
)

func main()  {
    http.HandleFunc("/home", index)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    getindex := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))
    getindex.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: Go については詳しくないのでコメントに留めますが、例えば `http://` 等で始まるURLを指定する必要があるのではないでしょうか？ブラウザのアドレス欄に `/home` と入力してアクセスできますか？

Comment: http.HandleFunc("home", index)の部分のところをhttp.HandleFunc("http://locolhost/home", index)に変えてもこのサイトにアクセスできませんって出ました(涙

Comment: ブラウザで `localhost/home` にアクセスした時、ページは表示されますか？ localhost を指定した場合は、自分のPC上で何かしらのwebサーバが起動している必要があると思います。

Comment: こちらの環境(Linux + golang 1.4)では問題ありませんでした。80 番ポートを listen するので root 権限が必要なのと、他の可能性としては `main.go` を実行したディレクトリに `index.html` がない、などが考えられます。

Comment: index.htmlを追加したけど今だにこのサイトにアクセスできませんってでる

Answer (score 0):

ファイアーウォールが作動しているのではないでしょうか？もしそうでしたら

```
$ sudo ufw allow 80
```

を実行すれば、サイトにアクセスできるのではないでしょうか？